# MongoDB: How to match on the elements of an array?

Tags: mongodb, match, lookup

I have two collections as follows:

```
db.qnames.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a4da53f97a9ca769a15d49e"), "domain" : "mail.google.com", "tldOne" : "google.com", "clients" : 10, "date" : "2016-12-30" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a4da55497a9ca769a15d49f"), "domain" : "mail.google.com", "tldOne" : "google.com", "clients" : 9, "date" : "2017-01-30” }
```

and

```
db.dropped.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a4da4ac97a9ca769a15d49c"), "domain" : "google.com", "dropDate" : "2017-01-01", "regStatus" : 1 }
```

I would like to join the two collections and choose the documents for which 'dropDate' field (from dropped collection) is larger than the 'date' filed (from qnames field). So I used the following query:

```
 db.dropped.aggregate( [{$lookup:{ from:"qnames", localField:"domain",foreignField:"tldOne",as:"droppedTraffic"}},
     {$match: {"droppedTraffic":{$ne:[]}  }}, 
{$unwind: "$droppedTraffic" } , 
{$match: {dropDate:{$gt:"$droppedTraffic.date"}}} ])
```

but this query does not filter the records where dropDate < date. Anyone can give me a clue of why it happens?

Comment: What is your mongo version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting the record is

> Date is used as a String in your collections, to make use of the comparison operators to get the desired result modify your collection documents using `new ISODate("your existing date in the collection")`

Please note even after modifying both the collections you need to modify your aggregate query, since in the final $match query two values from the same document is been compared.

Sample query to get the desired documents

```
db.dropped.aggregate([ 
    {$lookup: { 
       from:"qnames", 
       localField:"domain", 
       foreignField:"tldOne", 
       as:"droppedTraffic"}
    },
    {$project: {
       _id:1, domain:1, 
       regStatus:1,
       droppedTraffic: {
          $filter: { 
             input: "$droppedTraffic", 
             as:"droppedTraffic", 
             cond:{ $gt: ["$$droppedTraffic.date", "$dropDate"]}
          }
       }
     }} 
])
```

In this approach given above we have used [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) which avoids the [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operation

Answer (score 1):

You should use [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) to compare two fields of the same document. Following example should work:

```
db.dropped.aggregate( [
    {$lookup:{ from:"qnames", localField:"domain",foreignField:"tldOne",as:"droppedTraffic"}},
    {$match: {"droppedTraffic":{$ne:[]}  }}, 
    {$unwind: "$droppedTraffic" }, 
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$lte": [ "$dropDate", "$droppedTraffic.date" ] },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```